# Android facebook sdk login error 1118578

Tags: android, facebook

Everything was working fine, until I wanted to check what happens if the user clicks the Login with Facebook button with no internet connection available.

A toast showed up saying:

> Login failed. Please contact the maker of this app and ask them to report issue #1118578 to Facebook.

In the logcat I have:

> D/Facebook-authorize(2824): Login canceled by user.

I tried to get rid of this toast and display my own error message in the `onCancel()` method - but I can't find a way to disable that toast.
When I enabled WiFi again, single sign on didn't work anymore!

What could be the cause of this?

```
    private void fbLogin() {
    facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email" }, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            app.save("fb_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
            app.save("fb_expire", facebook.getAccessExpires());
            mAsyncRunner.request("me", new meRequestListener());
        }
        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}
        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

EDIT:

To answer my own question, removing `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` From the manifest in the `<activity>` resolved the #1118578 issue.

However, I do need the `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` for the twitter OAuth login, as the browser passes the data back to the activity via new Intent. If I do not provide `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in the manifest, a new activity is launched and it does not recieve the OAuth verifier.

**Is there any way around this, to use Facebook and Twitter login in the same activity?**
The only solution I think of is to use a dummy activity for Twitter4j with `singleInstance`.

Comment: I'm seeing the the 1118578 error without `launchMode` set (defaulting to standard), so there might be more to it than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My way to overcome this has been by changing the callback in twitter, from "twitter://callback" to "http://localhost/callback" and remove the android:launchMode="singleInstance" and the twitter intent-filter from the manifest.

I can still get the response in the WebView (rather than on the onResume() as before):

```
yourwebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  @Override
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // your_callback == http://localhost/callback
    if(url == null || !url.startsWith(your_callback))
      return;

    Uri         uri = Uri.parse(url);
    String      ov  = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
    AccessToken at  = null;
    ...
```